# Android Espresso ActivityTest gives 'package android.support.test.rule does not exist'

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am learning TDD for Android using this demo:

https://github.com/NileshJarad/TDD_Demo

I can run all the unit tests and the Mockito tests, but the "activityTests" fail with these errors:

```
error: package android.support.test.rule does not exist 
error: package android.support.test.espresso does not exist 
error: package android.support.test.espresso.action does not exist  
error: package android.support.test.espresso.action does not exist  
error: package android.support.test.espresso.action does not exist  
error: package android.support.test.espresso.assertion does not exist   
error: package android.support.test.espresso.matcher does not exist 
error: package android.support.test.espresso.matcher does not exist 
error: package android.support.test.espresso.matcher does not exist 
error: cannot find symbol class ActivityTestRule    
error: cannot find symbol method isDisplayed()  
...
```

The versions are Android 9.0 API 28.

I tried the suggestions at https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+ActivityTest+gives+%27package+android.support.test.rule+does+not+exist%27 but they all refer to `app/build.gradle` lines that we already have:

```
...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
...
dependencies {
...    
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just need to change the "rules" dependency to an AndroidX version:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
```

After syncing the project, you'll need to change your tests to use `androidx.test.*` instead of `android.support.test.*` (which you can do by deleting the greyed-out `import` statements and then just accepting all of the new imports that Android Studio suggests).

At this point, your tests should run!

One more thing: You can now delete the annotation at the top of your test class in which "AndroidJUnit4" is marked as deprecated (ie crossed out):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests), `@RunWith` is now only required when using a mix of `JUnit3` and `JUnit4` (which your test does not).